# implementing a search Bar

Tags: ios, swift

I am working on "implementing a search Bar"

When I work on "group table with multiple sections", Main.storyboard have *View Controller* and *Table View* it is run and display well like address list.

However, when I try to add the search Bar, I don't know how to deal with  Main.storyboard. If I only have *Table View Controller* 
I run it and display nothing.

If I have *View Controller* && *Table View* ,and also have Table View Controller, It have an error.

The code from the book is right, but to create Main.storyboard, the book explain very implicit.

By the way, what different between Table View Controller and use View Controller && Table View

Comment: What book? .. this question needs a lot of work if it is to remain open...

Comment: beginning iPhone development with swift

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The TableViewController comes with a tableView whose delegate and datasource are already set to be that TableViewController. This is normally used when it's ok for the table to take up the entire screen. The tableView is a normal view that you can add to any relevant ViewController. If this is the case, you must set its delegate and datasource and ensure that the corresponding ViewController conforms to UITableViewDelegate and UITableViewDataSource. The search bar would be a textField that would need a its delegate set. You can then write a search function to find whatever your text the user has in the textfield.

Comment: It is not a requirement that a table view's `delegate` be a view controller.  It is not a requirement that the `delegate` and the `dataSource` be the same class/instance.  It's not completely necessary that the text field be delegated.  We only care when the text has actually changed, and this isn't one of the delegate methods.